# What is the best way to api key passing to project?

Tags: python, java, api, authentication, parameter-passing

In my database project I am keeping all relavant files in some extra another file and mostly reading and passing to my code to make safer. But what about API keys for projects ?
Some people recommend to do as database logic in separate file, some of says pass as command line arguments ? What is the industry standards for those kinda situation.

```
import testapi

api_obj=testapi.connect('APIKEY')
```

What is the best way to pass api key to the project ?

Healthy Regards

Comment: Just a heads up that stuff passed on the command line is often visible via things like a simple `ps`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command line parameters or configuration file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322630/command-line-parameters-or-configuration-file)

Comment: If you are working on a Mac, then the `keyring` package lets you store secret info in your keyring and get it from there.  I presume there is something similar on other OSs.